# Weak solution of SDE, Tanaka equation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

A weak solution of  $$dX_t=b(t,X_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t)dB_t \;\;\;\; 0\let\le T, X_0=Z$$ is  a triple $(\tilde{X}_t,\tilde{B}_t,\mathcal{H}_t)$ such that the above equation hold and $\tilde{X}_t$ is $\mathcal{H}_t$-adapted and $\tilde{B}_t$ is an $\mathcal{H}_t$-Brownian motion, i.e. $\tilde{B}_t$ is a Brownian motion and $\tilde{B}_t$ is a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{H}_t$. In the weak solution of [Tanaka equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka_equation) what would be the filtration $\mathcal{H}_t$ and why would $\tilde{B}_t$ be adapted and a martingale with respect to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtration $\mathcal{H}_t$ could be the natural filtration of the process $\hat{B}_t$, or any filtration for which $\hat{B}_t$ is a Brownian motion. Since $\tilde{B}_t$ is given by a stochastic integral $$\tilde{B}_t = \int_0^t \mathrm{sgn}(\hat{B}_s)d \hat{B}_s$$
it is adapted to the underlying filtration (as all stochastic integrals of adapted processes are). Since $\mathrm{sgn}(\hat{B}_s)$ is in $L^2$, it follows that $\tilde{B}_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: thank you. It is not 100% clear why when if I take $\mathcal{H}_t$ to be a filtration with respect to which $\tilde{B}_t$ is a Brownian motion then the stochastic integral is adapted with respect to it.

Comment: @edamondo It is adapted because it is the $L^2$ limit of adapted processes.

Comment: Hmm, the limit of the simple processes? I am also wondering why the simple processes are adapted

Comment: A step stochastic process looks like $f(t,\omega ) = \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_{t_{i-1}} (\omega) 1_{[t_{i-1}, t_i)}(t)$ where $\xi_{t_{i}}$ is  $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$-measurable. Its integral is $\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_{t_{i-1}}(\omega) (B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}})$, where each summand is $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$ measurable. Adaptedness follows immediately.

Comment: Thanks. I am still a bit confused as to why $\tilde{B}_t$ is not a strong solution. We could do the same for the given Brownian motion $B_t$ and call $\tilde{B}_t=\int_0^t sgn(B_s)dB_s$ and by the same reasoning we would have adaptedness and the martingale property with respect to the standard Brownian filtration, so that this is a strong solution. There is a subtelty here that I think I don't get.

Comment: Also, it seems in the end that $\hat{B}_t$ is the solution since $d\hat{B}_t=sign(\hat{B}_t)d\tilde{B}_t$ so that we actually need $\mathcal{H}_t$ to be the filtration generated by $\tilde{B}_t$? Sorry, I find this topic very confusing.

Comment: @edamondo Yes, $\hat{B}_t$ will end up being the solution, but it's okay to take the filtration to be the one generated by $\hat{B}_t$. See Example 5.3.2 in Oksendal's book to see why this SDE does not admit a strong solution.

Comment: @edamondo Note that this is the flavour of weak solutions. Here we first construct the solution $X$, from which we extract a driving Brownian motion, rather than the other way round.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand more or less. The problem if I start with $\hat{B}_t=B_t$ is that at the end we have that $B_t$ is a solution of $dB_t=sign(B_t)d\tilde{B}_t$ and not of $dB_t=sign(B_t)d{B}_t$. Just I am still curious about something : Is $\tilde{B}_t:=\int_0^t sgn(B_s)dB_s$ a Brownian motion? Otherwise it is confusing to still denote it by the letter "B" I thought.

Comment: @edamondo Yes, $\tilde{B}$ is still a BM by Lévy's characterisation theorem.